# Java scheduled job stop for sometime then fired all at once

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, java-6

I have two classes:

1. Main class to run a scheduled job:

   ```
   public class TimerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       try {
           File logFile = new File("timer.log");
           TestTimerJob job = new TestTimerJob(logFile);
           Timer timer = new Timer();
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(job, 0, Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * 60 * 1000);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }  
   }
   ```
2. Job class simply write current datetime to a file (timer.log)

   ```
   public class TestTimerJob extends TimerTask {

   private File logFile;

   public TestTimerJob(File logFile) {
       this.logFile = logFile;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try {
           DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.logFile, true));
           writer.write(df.format(cal.getTime()));
           writer.newLine();
           writer.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Then i run the program with command:
`java -cp Test.jar test.TimerTest 1`
which means schedule above job to run every 1 minute.

I let it run for about 12 hours straight and when look at timer.log i found this:

```
2015/04/02 07:32:17
2015/04/02 07:33:17
2015/04/02 07:34:17
2015/04/02 07:35:17
2015/04/02 07:36:17
2015/04/02 07:37:17
2015/04/02 07:38:17
2015/04/02 07:39:17
2015/04/02 07:40:17
2015/04/02 07:41:17
2015/04/02 07:42:17
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:16
2015/04/02 08:02:17
2015/04/02 08:03:17
2015/04/02 08:04:17
2015/04/02 08:05:17
2015/04/02 08:06:17
2015/04/02 08:07:17
2015/04/02 08:08:17
```

Somehow it paused at `2015/04/02 07:42:17` then resumed at `2015/04/02 08:02:16` and run all the missfired schedules at once.

Can you explain what is this problem and how to fix it? I'm using jdk 1.6.0_34. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: From the javadocs: If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."  So we know that something is blocking your task.  My guess is has something to do with your log file access because substituting with a log4j call, your code runs perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the javadocs. So there is definitely something has block my program to run at that time. I check the windows's event viewer and found out that the power option of that virtual machine (sorry for not mention this in first place) was set to sleep after 30 mins. That makes everything clear.